# How to get value of row if checkbox in that row is clicked in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox

I would like to get value of whole row if same row check box checked. For example

```
 <table id="tbl" border="1">
    <tr><input type="checkbox" id="selectall"/>
        <td>
        <input type="checkbox"/></td>
 <td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
 <td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
 <td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="save"/>

$('#selectall').click(function(event) {
          if(this.checked) {
              // Iterate each checkbox
              $(':checkbox').each(function() {
                  this.checked = true;
              });
          }
          else {
            $(':checkbox').each(function() {
                  this.checked = false;
              });
          }

        });

$("#save").click(function(){
   /If all selected value has to pass through ajax one by one row/
});
```

If I press save button I have to select all row values which ever is checked. please refer this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hU89p/657/). Please help me . Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the desired data format

Comment: Dataformat should be array. So that I can get value like ['1','2'.'3'] if checked. or any other format that should be easy to parse if i pass ajax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```js
$('#selectall').click(function(event) {
  $(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
});

$("#save").click(function() {
  //reset the logger
  $('#log').empty();

  //get all the checked checboxex
  $('#tbl input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    //for each checked checkbox, iterate through its parent's siblings
    var array = $(this).parent().siblings().map(function() {
      return $(this).text().trim();
    }).get();
    //to print the value of array
    $('#log').append(JSON.stringify(array))
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="selectall" />
<table id="tbl" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="save" value="save" />
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: Hi dude. Can you please tell me now to change it as json format.

Answer (score 0):

You can get checked checkboxes and use `.closest()` to get their closest row elements object:

```
$('input:checked').closest('tr');
```

if you are looking forword to get the td elements with respect to checked checkbox then you can use:

```
$('input:checked').parent().siblings(); //if checkbox 3 is checked then it will have 3rd rows other three td elements having text 2,3,5.
```

**Update:** to get them in array

```
arr=[];
/If all selected value has to pass through ajax one by one row/
 $('input:checked').parent().each(function(){
   arr.push($(this).siblings().map(function(){
     return $(this).text()
   }).get());
 });
 console.log(arr);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/97abpe9y/)**